# Programmatically Determine location of headphone jack

Tags: java, android, hardware

Besides asking the user directly ..

Is there a way to determine whether the headphone jack is at the bottom or top of an android device??

Comment: I believe it wont be possible... Even in lowest levels, this kind of information is not stored..

Comment: Ah, this is a hardware thing. You might somewhere online find this fact for each of the phones. I am 99% sure that you cannot programmatically find this out.

Comment: There is a way, but it can cause the device to explode if the jack is on the side.

Comment: Need to determine this position as I am developing for a product that is inserted into your headphone jack and knowing it's position matters with respect to further calculations. I figured it'd be impossible to tell since it's manufacturer dependant; just thought I'd throw this out there. I've accepted the answer given. Thanks all !

Comment: Maybe you should request this API from Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no API for this.  It's hardware dependent and the framework and OS do not track/store this information.